# Extract images from EML file in C#

Tags: c#, extract, image, eml

I need to extract the images (attached) of a .EML file.
Any help or ideas?
Thanks in advance.
(I'm programming in c#)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get that with Sasa.net, though I haven't used the MIME portion I've been surprised by its completeness otherwise.  You'll find sample usage of Sasa.net to scan EML files here: https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole/blob/master/SampleConsole/DumpEmlFilesCommand.cs

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean .eml (a file containing contents mime-encoded message), take a look at some of MIME implementations for your language, for instance, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MIME_De_Encode_in_C_.aspx or http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpmimetools/